# How to make Square to send transaction reports automatically?

Tags: square-connect

I need Square to send transaction reports to my app in real time. Not to request it from my app, but square to send it itself.

1. Does square has this feature?
2. Is that procedure standardized for POS software? Any standard protocol for it?

Answer (score 0):

1. No
2. No :(

But you are welcome to setup a service with Square's [webhooks](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/webhooks-in-the-square-connect-api-d4d38c4b4d9f) to push `transaction reports` to your application.